# form submit fails with more than one date_select helper in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm having trouble with Rails' date helper

> date_select

If I only have one in the form then the form submits perfectly to the database but if I add another date_select helper tag to my form then I receive the following error:

> ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors in Admin::StudentRegistrationsController#create
>
> 1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes

My controller is the usual scaffold one:

```
# POST /student_registrations
# POST /student_registrations.xml
def create
@student_registration = StudentRegistration.new(params[:student_registration])
respond_to do |format|
if @student_registration.save
format.html { redirect_to(@student_registration, :notice => 'Student registration was successfully created.') }
format.xml  { render :xml => @student_registration, :status => :created, :location => @student_registration }
else
format.html { render :action => "new" }
format.xml  { render :xml => @student_registration.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
end
```

and my view is as follows:

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @student_registration]) do |f| %>
<div class="reg_title">
Date of Birth
</div>
<div class="reg_content">
<%= f.date_select(:DOB,:start_year => 1940) %>
</div>
<div class="reg_title">
Passport Expiry Date
</div>
<div class="reg_content">
<%= f.date_select(:PPortE,:start_year => 1940) %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Inside my params the dates are coming together so there are no blanks:

> "DOB(1i)"=>"1979",
> "DOB(2i)"=>"9",
> "DOB(3i)"=>"4",
> "PPortE(1i)"=>"2012",
> "PPortE(2i)"=>"1",
> "PPortE(3i)"=>"4"},

but, again if I comment out the Passport exp date_select the rest of the form will submit.  Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved.  The issue was the data type in the database for passport exp date, it was set to VARCHAR instead of DATE for some reason.  The result of working with a legacy database I suppose!

Comment: I had the same problem today. I noticed this question which prompted me to take a look at my migration - I'd put date_of_birth as a :string instead of :date. Thanks for solving your own query!